# Reshaping a numpy array in a function doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy

... but changing the values of the numpy array works:

```py
import numpy as np

def reshapeArray(arr):
    arr = arr.reshape((2, 2))
    arr /= 10
    print(arr) # prints [[0.1 0.3], [0.2 0.4]]

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.float32)
reshapeArray(arr)
print(arr) # prints [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]
```

The `reshapeArray()` function changed values of the array permanently, but changed the shape of the array temporarily. If I add a return line (`return arr`) to end of the function, and assign the output of the function to the array `(arr = reshapeArray(arr))`, this time it works. But I wonder why it didn't work without returning the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs ([numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)):

> This will be a new view object if possible; otherwise, it will be a
>   copy. Note there is no guarantee of the memory layout (C- or Fortran-
>   contiguous) of the returned array.

As opposed to `arr = arr / 10`, which does makes a copy and reassigns it.

Apparently a view is lost when leaving scope...

Comment: The `arr=...` breaks the back reference. That's basic python function variable scoping.  The `view` is a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return an array from function and assign the returned value to the desired variable:

```
    return arr  # The last string of your function

arr = reshapeArray(arr)
```

Comment: Note that OP explicitly said that's something they've tried (and know that it works) but would like to know *why* this works.